# I am trying to run my flutter application but it was showing "Flutter Tool cannot access the file or directory" this error

Tags: flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception: The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

I tried to change the directory of project but still the same error. I tried to run another project from the same directory, It was running fine.

Here is flutter doctor output :

```
sahil@Sahils-MacBook-Air ~ % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```